# Logical calculation issue

Tags: c#

I have a control square with user defined height, top range and bottom range values.
There is a line in between the control which divides the top range and bottom range.

User will provide another value "fillValue" too.

Problem:

For instance:

```
height = 100;
topRange = 10;
bottom range= 10;
fillValueTop= 5;
```

Now here I have to decide what percentage 5 will be for the toprange. Basically the height of fill for upper side of the square.
with same height, toprange and bottomrange, the user can change fillValueTop = 40. In this case 
what percentage should get filled for the upper side of the square?

Similarly, it could be,

```
   height = 200;
   topRange = 15;
   bottomrange= 15;
   fillValueBottom= 20;
```

Basically I need to calculate the percentage of fill depending on the above parameters.

Can someone help me with some formular or so.

I thought something like this.

```
     var unit = height/(topRange + bottomrange);
         var actualFillValue = unit*fillValueTop;
```

But I think it does not work.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Why have topRange and  bottomrange the same value? Why do you think this does not work?

Comment: actually the topRange=+15 (positive value), and bottomrange=-15(negative value, but ofcourse I do Math.Abs(bottomrange) while applying it to my formula). If it is positive value I fill the upper part and if negative I fill the lower part. I feel it does not work because when I use the values the fill percentage does not seem to be correctly calculated. It feels my square more than expected.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're asking. This may be because I lack some background knowledge that makes it obvious what your question means. On the other hand it may be because you have not specified your question clearly enough.

Comment: Review your question and correct the code snippets